# How much explanation is "good"? Am I "overdoing" it?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality, quality-improvement

Yesterday I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34460410/2173917), with a broader, step-by-step logical reasoning as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460449/2173917).

While I personally believe my answer would be helpful for the OP (and also other people who'll come down to this question seeking solutions), while revisiting the answer today, I got a feeling: *"Am I overdoing it?"*

Let me explain my two thoughts clearly.

- **First:** When I came across the question, I started writing the answer. In the meantime, another answer got posted which addressed the issue clearly. I read the answer, and it appeared fine. However, *I thought* it needed some more clarification on the actual behavior of the operators used so that, at a later stage, anyone reading this answer should be able to handle much more complex statements involving these operators *themselves*. So, I went on writing my answer and posted it finally, which is a rather *longer* one, containing each step-by-step explanation of how to get the answer. At that point of time, I was happy because I thought I wrote a *complete answer.*

<sup>*P.S - My answer got accepted by OP, if that matters in this context.*</sup>

- **Second:** Today while revisiting my answer to see any scope of improvement, I suddenly felt the answer was *too* long, and *too* elaborate, more appropriate to be posted on a tutorial site, but maybe not as an answer in SO. OK, I know I have added some citations and additional info; that is fine, but the step-by-step-by-step explanation is just *too much*. Even without the *complete* explanation, anybody having read the rest of the answer should be able to get the concept. Instead, I added *all* the explanations in my answer. Should I have added a required minimal explanation and have pointed to a tutorial in addition?

Now my question to the community: Am I doing it right?

- If yes, fine.
- If no, please suggest how I can limit my answers. I mean to say, any good examples of how to write a short but complete and helpful answer is all I am looking for.

Honestly, I believe that, instead of giving someone a fish, (*spoonfeeding*), if I can make someone learn how to *catch a fish*, I'll be helping in a better way. However, sometimes, firstly giving the fish **and** then making them learn is not a bad approach, either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Everything under 30,000 characters is fine ...

Comment: @rene that is what I also believe and thats the reason i added the answer. However, I just want to know whether I'm repeating a most obvious thing inside an answer and whether a link to further reading will be helpful in this context or not? Hope I am able to clarify me question. :)

Comment: Seems quite short to me. I much prefer your answer over some "Try this" with a block of code. Although for the specifics of the question, the other answer in that topic also is fine to me. I tend to answer broadly to be more inclusive to future searchers.

Comment: Shorter answers tend to get more votes.  If that concerns you then just do it both ways.  Start with the short one, elaborate in next paragraphs.

Comment: I only have a bit of an issue with the first sentence as it seems to rely on the full discussion (which is not present anymore). That should be a short explanation instead, as indicated by Hans Passant above. As this one is pretty tailored to one user specific issue it's not something I would consider a deal breaker though. If I was a C expert I would happily upvote the answer (I'm not doing so now because I think the question is a bit too localized).

Comment: Be [that guy](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/). Seriously. It's great!

Comment: @HansPassant: I find that shorter "here are the codez" answers without explanation get more votes in the short term (probably because voters are lazy) but more detailed answers do better over time (probably because they actually help people).

Comment: I feel that everything you are discussing here is reasonably obvious to anyone who has read a few answers, and feel a little suspicious that this is an attempt to get more recognition for your answer via the Meta Effect.

Comment: @jwg I understand your thinking, but, in that case, I have many more answers which are more elaborate than the _accepted and upvoted_ ones. Why do you think I brought this one up, particularly? :) I do not have an issue with _quick and dirty_ answers myself and if my answer is worthy, it will get up-voted anyway, with or without meta effect. The issue I tried to get clarified is, am I encouraging someone to ask the most basics as a question instead of pointing them to a tutorial first?

Comment: I don't want to accuse you of dishonesty - there is nothing wrong with your answer or this question. But clearly there *is* a meta effect, and posting a meta question which points to an answer which you **know** is useful (because it was already upvoted) is going to get you some extra upvotes. Nothing you have said in your comment changes this.

Comment: My 2c: you are just one individual ‒ it's totally fine, and even good, if multiple S.O. users answer a question in different level of detail. Recall that questions are there **for all of us**, not only for the person who asked the question. Thus, someone may appreciate your detailed answer, and someone else competing short answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, *I definitely don't believe you're overdoing it*. You didn't spiral off in a writing adventure explaining things that are completely unrelated to the question in hand. What you did was *stayed within the scope of the problem* (operations with the `&&` and `||` operators) and just added quotes from the documentation, breaking down the operation in the question is also a major plus. *That's a solid answer in my book*.

I like elaborating too (when I can) and provide as much information for answers I give. I've only noticed one case where it might be counter-productive: You write out a wall out text and *don't make it clear **where** the anwer lies*. In these cases I always like to break my answer in two 'sections':

- **Short Answer**: A quick answer that clearly solves the problem in a tl;dr fashion. This part is directed towards people looking for a quick answer to a given problem who don't really care about additional information.
- **Long Answer**: A more in-depth explanation for those readers that might be interested in a broaded picture of the problem in hand (spiraling away from the main issue is probably the most common pit-fall here).

I think this 'methodology' doesn't apply to your linked answer as it is but it can be something to have in mind if you find yourself answering questions whose `size > computer screen`.

---

Those are my two cents, I think *overdoing* it is not necessarely a bad thing if you know your stuff (resulting in good content) and have the ability to organize it in such a way that people with different needs can parse it and focus on what they want. (making good content easier to follow).

To wrap up, it's a solid answer and I would urge you to continue explaining things. Worry not about the size; if the answer gets long just manage it in ways where your points and your answer becomes clear.

Comment: If the answer uses [inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid) then it may be as long as the system can bear.

Comment: It's worth remembering that the point of stack overflow isn't just to give the supplicant an answer - it's to give future readers an answer. So being as comprehensive as possible is only a good thing... just remember to summarise at the top, so people who _do_ understand don't need to wade through it all.

Answer (score -33):

I think one should not feel like a **teacher** while answering questions in SO.

It would be nice to count on the reader's IQ, programming abilities, etc.

You may just point to the right direction and mention the key notes, while putting the rest to the audience.

Comment: Personally, I try to tailor the complexity of my answer to what I perceive as the knowledge level of the asker. I've answered (relatively) harder questions on collision detection where I explain the [Separating Axis theorem and axis aligned bounding boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32748251/1828486), and I've answered simple beginner questions where I explain [how a switch statement works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32488776/1828486). The key is to make sure your answer is complete so that future users can read the question and answer pair and understand the topic fully.

Comment: I think this answer is completely against the spirit of Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a help site. It's not a place where you come along, drop your problem in front of someone, and wait for it to get solved. It is a place where you come when you *have a gap in your knowledge*, and you ask a question to try to fill that gap. Every answer *is* teaching. That's the spirit of the whole site: teach people about the problem and the solution so they leave having *learned* and filled their knowledge gap and can solve their own problem now.

Comment: Teaching is something really different from feeling like a teacher.

Comment: You may want to improve your post by editing it to show what you mean by "feeling like a teacher". If you mean that you don't have to show a step by step process (_"Open your IDE, start a new project, create a new class"_) for a question about polymorphism, then yeah...

Comment: That's exactly what I mean