# Am I doing too much?

Tags: discussion, answers

I often answer technical questions in the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tags. I've noticed lately, I often feel like I *overexplain*. An example would be me linking to the ECMAScript 2015 specification where large amounts of specification are quoted and explained. Is this encouraged? Should I just link to something like MDN which explains behavior but does not explain concisely why? I don't want to waste anybody's time, but I still want to provide adequate information for the asker for a complete answer. Is doing too much and overexplaining bad?

Comment: There is strength in brevity. That said, linking to official documentation never hurts.

Comment: @TravisJ I agree, but I have answers such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42498163/5647260) where most of the answer is the HTML Spec, but it explains it (and is lengthy!). Would it be better to refrain from this kind of answer or should it be encouraged?

Comment: That answer looks appropriate to me. It was even accepted by the OP as solving their problem. In my experience here, too much information in an answer (so long as it is correct) has never been a problem.

Comment: Respecting the time of the reader is generally a good idea, in my experience short answers tend to attract more votes.  Just do both, start your post with a summary of the answer and expound on details in the second section.  It doesn't always work, it gets hard to do this when the question is inadequately researched.

Comment: It's worth noting that "just link to something like MDN" could make your answer a link-only one, and subject to deletion. I'm not sure exactly what you meant by it, but if you meant "post an answer that is nothing but a link to part of a specification or some documentation", then... yeah.

Comment: `An example would be me linking to the ECMAScript 2015 specification where [it is] quoted and explained. Is this encouraged?` In my opinion, **YES**. I think any answer coming here for a cheap and quick answer to a question without caring much about the _'Why?'_ or any in-depth reasoning is **doing themselves a disservice** to their own education and potentially their career. Complete, high quality answers with references to the specification are an instant upvote for a reason -- they're _important_.

Comment: @Andrew Li For me Not at all keep the good work up!

Comment: @AndrewLi I has exactly same doubt sometimes ago, [see this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313420/2173917)

Comment: [This comic](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/) may or may not be based on you ;)

Comment: Both types of answers, both brief and precise are complementary to each other. Some people will need a quick, practical and easily understandable answer to a question, others will have a specific very technical problem and will love you for linking to specifications and explaining their complex conclusions.

Comment: Rather more, than [too little](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/299295).

Comment: You can have both. A short introductuion that explains the behavior and links to MSDN, followed by an in-depth explanation that quotes the spec. That way you get the best of both worls, and readers wo aren#t interested in details can stop after the first part.

Comment: I often find a three part answer effective:  executive summary, short answer, long answer.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[I'm probably biased](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+url%3A%22w3.org%2FTR%2F*%22), but don't worry about quotes from the specification being "too much". As long as you only quote the relevant portions of the spec, and use them to support your explanations of why certain things work a certain way, you're doing fine.

Your example answer quoting the HTML spec is stellar. Keep it up.

Comment: Came here to say "just look at BoltClock's answers" :-P

Answer (score 32):

This is just an opinion but I find that in the  Stack Exchange network, Stack Overflow in particular blurs the line between pragmatism and learning. Many of the most successful answers basically start with a TL;DR with the solution and then fill out the rest of the answer with a much more involved explanation including specs et. al.
Personally in my workflow at my job I will often use the solution and put the answer in my pocket or collect the link then read the full explanation in my free time. Either way thanks for being here to answer. I for one really appreciate it.

Comment: I think the *learning* part is key here. The TL;DR is mainly useful for the OP, however the lengthy explanation is useful for everyone who stumbles upon the situation and needs to actually understand what's going on to be able to adapt the solution to their needs.