# How lengthy can an answer be?

Tags: discussion, answers

After several edits, adding comments to the code example, adding screenshots and so on, [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603066/7571258) grew somewhat in length.

How much is too much, especially regarding code samples?

As OP seems to be beginner level (and we have to assume that for everyone who reads our answers), I felt the need to go into much detail, especially as "Solution 2" isn't that trivial to get right. I could have provided only general hints and some links to the API documentation but that propably wouldn't be that helpful. You can only get so much from reference docs (especially if it comes from a known big software manufacturer ;-)).

So I added a code sample that can be used "as is", has complete error handling and uses techniques that I think are "best practice".

Often when I stumble upon "official" code samples the error handling is at best "rudimentary". But I believe people are lazy and will just copy-paste code samples without adding their own error handling, even if there is a big red hint that the author omitted error handling for "brevity". 
I believe "brevity" is a bad excuse for laziness of the author, so I tend to provide verbose code samples.

But maybe such verbosity is not wanted here on SO and I should shorten my code samples? Or possibly move code that exceeds a certain length to some external side like gist.github.com?

Comment: There are plenty of very long but good answers on SO. If you are worried about it being too long, put the main points and resolution at the beginning. Then those who want to look at more detail can read further if so inclined.

Comment: *"How lengthy can an answer be?"* 30,000 characters.

Comment: Well, this answer is at 41% so there is still room to grow ;-) A summary at the beginning is a good suggestion though.

Comment: Here are some good answers to a [similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344907/7571258).

Comment: a detailed answer of 30,000 characters will always win out on an answer with a 30,000 character code dump

Comment: When you find yourself posting multiple comments to your own answer, with nobody else contributing anything, then you are probably overdoing it a bit.

Comment: I went with the suggestion of @codeMagic and added a summary at the beginning. Is it possible to link to sub headers of the answer? `<a href="#solution1">...</a>` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall limit is 30000 characters.

Answers that are close to the max size frequently fall behind in votes after shorter more practical answers. Providing summary / TL;DR; section in the beginning will make such answer more accessible.

There is no expectation that samples provide 100% error handling. It is also rarely possible to provide copy-paste-ready  error handling (especially in C/C++) due to larger variety of error handling paradigms. It may be better to outline error handling as `// TODO` comments. Same as for overall content it may be good idea to provide most important part of the code early and move detailed sample toward the end of the post. Hosting sample code outside of SO is not really welcome for essential part of sample, linking to version controlled public location is fine for extra detailed samples or complete project.

Note that code should follow good coding practices for language/frameworks used in the question, but there is no expectation that answer provides ready to copy-paste answer to the question or fixes typos in the question leaving other major issues in the asnwer. Most obvious case - code with SQL injection should not be provided as answer. So it is fine balance of too long sample and one that seriously cuts corners.